# Why is the ui-select not clearing on selection every 2nd time?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ui-select

In `ui-select`, when I select an option, the `on-select` callback does fire, but the option does not clear every second time.

The ui-select has 2 states:

1. Button - when I do not actually click it
2. Input - when I click in it and it lets me search

When it starts, the button has my placeholder text "Search...". I click it, start to search, it brings up a list, I select one option, `on-select` fires, in which I clear the `ng-model`.

Yet, every second select I do, it ignores the `ng-model` clear in my callback.

```
<ui-select ng-model="result.selected" theme="bootstrap" class="search" on-select="searchselect($item)" reset-search-input="true" on-select="selected($item)">
    <ui-select-match placeholder="Search...">{{$select.selected.name}}</ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices refresh="search({val:$select.search})" refresh-delay="300" repeat="item in results">
        <div ng-bind="item.name"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
</ui-select>
```

Here is my `on-select` code:

```
  $scope.selected = function(item) {
     $scope.picked = item;
     $scope.result.selected = "";
  };
```

I modified the basic `ui-select` example plunkr to replicate it: http://plnkr.co/edit/16DRYH8MbPJOy0GpogZz?p=preview

1. Click on the select
2. Search for text, I find "123" to be easiest
3. Select an option
4. See that the `ng-model` is cleared
5. Search *again*
6. Select another option, or the same one
7. See that the `ng-model` is not cleared

Here are images.

Initial:

[image: Initial]

During search:

[image: Select]

After select (every 2nd one) - **this is my problem**

[image: After select PROBLEM]

Why is it not cleared in the button last image after every 2nd select?

Answer (score 0):

late, but maybe it helps: I guess it has something to do with an incorrect implementation of the angular-digest cycle in ui-select. [See scope lifecycle of the angular documentation.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

So, what can you do about that:

- Wrap all modifications on scope that you do on the selected-callback in an $timeout, as angular automatically wraps everything in there in a safe digest cycle. 
  Example:

  ```
  $scope.selected = function(item) {
    $timeout(function(){
      $scope.picked = item;
      $scope.result.selected = "";
    }); 
  };
  ```
- Use a $watch expression instead of the callback function:

  ```
  $scope.$watch('result.selected', function(newVal){
    if(newVal !== ''){
      $scope.picked = newVal;
      $scope.result.selected = '';
    }
  });
  ```

I guess the latter is more efficient, as it does not trigger a complete digest cycle. (but I'm not an expert on angular internals.)

Comment: I ended up spending far too much time digging into this, and I think (but am not sure) you are right about the causes. I ended up fixing it by putting my own directive on it. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/issues/502